# How to automatically select the appropriate threshold for peak detection

Tags: python, statistics

I wrote a code using python to detect singular points from a dataset. In order to detect peaks i must put a threshold `T` but that's specific for one sample of data which means i have to change the threshold for each new data. Any idea of how to improve my code so that it will calculate automatically the threshold (`T` in the code) maybe using Std deviation, rate change or somehting like that.

To summarize i want the `T`(which is the threshold for peak detection) to be calcultated automatically from the dataset instead of trying some random values.

[image]

Thanks

```
tab = np.array(data).astype(str).astype(np.float)
aux=tab[0][0]
index=[]
index.append(0)
i=1

while i <= len(tab)-2:
    while ( ((tab[i][0]>aux+T) or (tab[i][0]<aux-T))
        aux=tab[i][0]
        SP.append(aux)
        index.append(i)
        break
    i=i+1
.
.
.
```

Comment: Analyze what you, as a person, would classify as peaks. Then calculate the average standard deviation for these manually classified peaks. Eg. on average peaks on average are 2 std deviations away from the mean. If the mean changes over time, use a rolling mean with rolling std deviations.

Comment: Sorry i didnt get your point, you mean instead of computing std deviation for whole data i would use rolling std for limited number of observations ?